# lein repl results in java.lang.AssertionError (transport-fn)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

If I create a new app with lein:

```
lein new app hw
```

Change to the **hw** directory and try to start a REPL:

```
lein repl
```

I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: transport-fn, compiling:(/private/var/folders/58/67rnbq5d1mnd59sq6hcqk7qc0000gp/T/form-init8844387568772172781.clj:1:125)

I had, as of a week or two ago, a perfectly functional Clojure/lein environment. I've mess with my Java, so I thought maybe that was the issue, but changing between two versions of Java 8, or using Java 9 or 10 doesn't change anything, and Clojure versions 1.8, 1.9 and 1.10-RC5 also result in the same transport-fn error.

I'm using lein 2.8.2 on Mac Mojave 10.14.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it seems to be a bug in lein 2.8.2. https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2497. You can downgrade with: `lein upgrade 2.8.1`. Credit to the clojurians slack channel.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on a Mac and used Brew so, I had to do "brew switch lein 2.8.1" to fix it, but that was the right idea. Also it explains how it happened, since I must've accidentally done a global "brew upgrade" or something. Thanks again!